# Does Wireshark sends or receives any additional packets when it's capturing?

Tags: networking, wireshark, pppoe

My problem is my ISP has a pppoe client(only for windows) which forbids the use of VPN/proxx to share Internet connection.
My friend cracked its encryption algorithm so we are able to build a new client on our own(linux/windows), and it's been working well for 1 year now.
However, my ISP changed its pppoe client this year, our algorithm still works, but the connection will be closed every few minutes, so we have to use the ISP's client again.

I start using Wireshark to capture packets, hoping to find some kind of a "heart beat" protocol, but the weird thing is once I started capturing packets, the connection was never closed.

So, I am wondering, does Wireshark sends or receives any additional packets when it's capturing that make my connection never closed by my ISP?

If not, what could be the reason for the weird thing happened above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIreshark captures packets. It doesn't send them.

I am unable to help you with your task of defrauding your ISP.

Comment: Well, you may have misunderstood my motivation, I just want to make my laptop, Android phone, and my test server at home share the same Internet connection, so I don't have to pay 4 times to my ISP, but my ISP here in China doesn't allow that, so the use some kind of encryption to prevent that.

Comment: My ISP doesn't even allow me to use a wireless router to share connection between my devices, so I don't think what I am doing is wrong

Comment: and it's even impossible to use Internet on Android devices because my ISP simply doesn't provide me a client

Comment: Further more, China Telecom has monopolized the ISP market, I can't choose any other companies because they are not allowed

Comment: So if you think there is a more proper way to do this, please tell me @EJP, and I will be very grateful

Comment: @CarlLee I expect your ISP has another level of service where you are allowed to route/share.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, at least not allowed in the campus where I am living in (my university has signed contract with China Telecom to rule out other competitor), and they don't support any other platform other than windows.

Comment: If I don't want the expensive plan (￥50/month with 100 KB/s downlink and 40 KB/s uplink), and the unreasonable service, I have 2 choice, crack the client, or move out of school(which would be ￥300/month more expensive)

Comment: @CarlLee so the statement in my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, it's not me who downvoted you, I saw it wrong, I thought U downvoted me, not you who was being downvoted. You answer is correct absolutely